# Unable to reach the content stored within iframes

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

For the last few hours I've been trying to fix a simple issue but can't figure out where I'm going wrong. There is a webpage in which there are `two srarch boxes` to be filled in to populate the result; one for `street number` and the other for `street name`. The two search terms are already set within the `.SendKeys` in my below script so that you can run it as it is.

There are three `iframes` to deal with to reach the content. First `iframe` appears in the landing page in which the `search boxes` are. I've switched it. However, the last two `nested iframes` appear in the result page. I've switched the first one (from the result page) but can't switch the last one to reach the content I'm looking for. I'm trying to extract `VANDREUMEL SILVIA HERNANDEZ` this name under the table captioned with the header `Ownership History`.

When it comes to switch the second `iframe` (named as `quickframe` which is the `id`), it throws an error `element not found error`. How can I solve this problem in order to get the `owner name`?

> Once again, search terms are:
>
> `street no.` which should be `10023`
>
> `street name` which should be `HARDISON LN`
>
> Then hit the search button to populate the results.

This is my attempt so far:

```
Sub CollectInformation()
    Dim post As Object
    
    With New ChromeDriver
        .get "http://hcad.org/quick-search/"
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", Timeout:=7000)
        .FindElementById("s_addr", Timeout:=7000).Click
        .FindElementByCss("input[name='stnum']", Timeout:=7000).SendKeys "10023"
        .FindElementByCss("input[name='stname']", Timeout:=7000).SendKeys "HARDISON LN"
        .FindElementByCss("input[value='Search']", Timeout:=10000).Click
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe", Timeout:=7000)
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("quickframe", Timeout:=10000) ''error thrown here
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss("th", Timeout:=7000)
            If InStr(1, post.Text, "VANDREUMEL", 1) > 0 Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text: Exit For
        Next post
        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

Btw, If you manually try the link to see the `search boxes` then you need to click on `search by address` in order for that `search boxes` to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right frame already

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CollectInformation()
    With New ChromeDriver
        .get "http://hcad.org/quick-search/"
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=7000)
        .FindElementById("s_addr", timeout:=7000).Click
        .FindElementByCss("input[name='stnum']", timeout:=7000).SendKeys "10023"
        .FindElementByCss("input[name='stname']", timeout:=7000).SendKeys "HARDISON LN"
        .FindElementByCss("input[value='Search']", timeout:=10000).Click
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe", timeout:=7000)

        Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("input[name=searchval]", timeout:=7000).Attribute("value")  '<== Just the name

        ' Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("tbody th:nth-child(2)", timeout:=7000).Text  '<== Header i.e. Name and address

    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Output for just the name:**

[image: CSS selector]

[image: name only]

---

**Output for header:**

That `th` tag contains the name and address

[image: css query]

[image: Output]

Comment: Yes, you made it @QHarr. So, the first `iframe` is just the placeholder!! Wasn't that a little tricky?

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem has already been resolved, I decided to come up with a robust solution. If you follow the way I tried below, you no longer worry about the `iframes`. All you need to do is send `POST` request using the proper `headers` along with the appropriate `ActiveX` in which you will get `cookie` support. However, `Microsoft WinHTTP Services` is the right candidate for you to achieve the same.

This is how you can go:

```
Sub CollectInformation()
    Dim Http As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim oelem As Object

    With Http
        .Open "POST", "https://public.hcad.org/records/QuickSearch.asp", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send "search=addr"
    End With

    With Http
        .Open "POST", "https://public.hcad.org/records/QuickRecord.asp", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://public.hcad.org/records/QuickSearch.asp"
        .send "TaxYear=2018&stnum=10023&stname=HARDISON+LN"
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set oelem = Html.querySelector("input[name=searchval]")
    If Not oelem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox oelem.getAttribute("value")
    End If
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1
```

Output:

[image]